# C# How return a default value when referencing a user defined class?

Tags: c#, class, default, poco

I have a C# class that I'd like to reference and return the value of a specific property, fieldValue.  I currently do it by using "ToString()" but I'd like to be able to just reference the class name and get the value.  There are a number of use cases I have but the important thing is to know how to do this specific thing.  The class looks like:

```
public class FieldSet
{
    public FieldSet() { }

    public string fieldName { get; set; }
    public string fieldType { get; set; }
    public string fieldValue { get; set; }

    public FieldSet(string fName, string fType, string fValue)
    {
        fieldName = fName;
        fieldType = fType;
        fieldValue = fValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return fieldValue;
    }
}
```

In use:

```
FieldSet rec = new FieldSet { fieldName = "ID", fieldType = "String", fieldValue = "6" };

string s = rec.ToString() //  s = "6"
string s = rec            // I'd like to s = "6" as well
```

So, how can I modify the FieldSet class to return the fieldValue by just referencing the class name?

Comment: This is not possible in C#, because the notation `string s = rec` is always used to assign an object to a variable. Implicit conversion won't help you because implicit functions always need to be static. You can't use the non-static field `fieldValue` within a static function.

Comment: Makes sense... damn... ;-)